# How to use "may" twice in one sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, modal-verbs

I would like to use a quite long sentence to reflect my idea. For this sentence, I would like to use the word *may*. I found that I need to use it twice in the same sentence. However, I do not know if my sentence would be understandable or not, or if it is acceptable by the English grammar or not.

Here is my sentence:

> Fixing the type of relationship between variables to a small set of dependency types may not adequate enough to reflect the dependencies, which may not include in the dependencies set.

I see that my sentence is long, however, this is my best way to do it.

Comment: The sentence is ungrammatical, but that aside, I see only one *may* in it. See [this website](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/may-might-may-have-and-might-have) on how and when *may* is generally used.

Comment: There are some errors in the sentence, but the use of *may* is fine.  There's no rule against using the same word twice in one sentence.

Comment: How about "Defining the relationship"? Do you need "type of"?

Comment: @Lambie, yes I need to use type of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

"Reducing the relationships between variables to a small set of dependency types may not adequately enough reflect all the dependencies, since some may be missing from the dependencies set."

In any case, you may use the word may as often as you may like in one sentence.